# Как обновить css из js?

Tags: ajax, html, css, javascript

Всем привет.

Вношу некие данные ajax`ом в див. Грубо говоря, это тоже дивы.
Так вот вопрос: как заставить после добавления таких данных страницу применить стили css к вновь добавленным дивам (они не подхватывают css).
Желательно, с помощью js.

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Никак заставлять не надо. В нормальном состоянии css применяется ко всем элементам, как изначальным так и динамически вставленным. Если вы вставляете данные и к ним не применяются стили - значит стили у вас не написаны для тех элементов.

Comment: Вау, +10!!

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, да уж )) Перельману меньше почестей за доказательство гипотезы Пуанкаре было ))

Comment: по-моему как раз для таких случаев придумали знак "Дисциплина"... +12 и растет, жесть ваще.

Answer (score 1):

вот тут есть динамическое подключение стилей

http://scriptjava.net/documentation

так же есть такое понятие как !important

http://htmlbook.ru/css/!important

можно конечно сразу подключить все стили

Answer (score 0):

Не силен в js, но может быть что-то типа `Update` к общему классу типа `windows` и перерисовать его.

Comment: в том то и дело что неохото перерисовывать(дабы не вызвать мерцание).
хотелось бы имеено "рефреш" css

Answer (score 0):

Стили применяются автоматически.
Возможно проблема в том, что при загрузке ajax'ом отсутствуют пробелы между `inline-block`. В этом случае блоки не будут выравниваться с помощью `text-align`.
Добавьте пробел в подгружаемые данные и все будет ок.